# .htaccess RewriteRule $1 contains wrong value

Tags: apache, htaccess

I have a RewriteRule that is not behaving as I expect. I want `site.com/author/fred` to map to `site.com/author/index.php?a=fred`

I have an author directory within the site root. The author directory contains the .htaccess file below.

My problem is that `$1` contains the value `index.php` instead of the regex match.

The entire .htaccess file is below. Can you see my mistake? Thank you.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$  index.php?a=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your pattern `([^/]+)/?$` will match `fred` as well as `index.php`.

The key here -- the way how `[L]` flag works. After initial rewrite of `fred` occurs it goes to next rewrite iteration, where it will rewrite `index.php?a=fred` to `index.php?a=index.php`. Because URL was rewritten, it goes to 3rd iteration, where `index.php?a=index.php` will be rewritten to the same URL `index.php?a=index.php`. Because input and output URLs are the same, rewrite exits and you have what you have right now.

**You need to add a condition to prevent looping.** For example (one of the possible approaches):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php$
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$  index.php?a=$1 [NC,L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$  index.php?a=$1 [NC,L]
```

or even

```
RewriteRule (?!index\.php)([^/]+)/?$  index.php?a=$1 [NC,L]
```

Read a bit more: [RewriteRule Last [L] flag not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797998/rewriterule-last-l-flag-not-working)